# Can't connect to Azure database on Sever although the connection String is right. 1042 error

Tags: c#, mysql, azure

Im trying to connect to MySQL database on Azure through C#. I am using MySQLConnector package for my program.
I have admin account so I can easily access to the database through Sever Explorer in Visual Studio in SSH Sever Authentication . However I can not do the same with C#. I even tried to copy the exact connection string given by Sever Explorer but I still cant connect to my database through C# . I always get the error "1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." . The connection String from Sever Explorer provide necessary param : Data Source, Inital Catalog, Persist Security Info, User ID and Password.

As I have admin account. I have also tried to copy the connection String provided from Azure Portal for ADO.net. The connection String look a bit different . For example it provide extra parameter like 
TrustServerCertificate, Encrypt, MultipleActiveResultSets. However if I used this connection string, the program does not compile. Visual Studio tell me the these parameters are not supported . For example :'Option 'MultipleActiveResultSets' not supported.' etc. If I deleted those paratemters, I have the same 1042 error.  Please help me, I am new. Thanks

The Connection String from Sever Explorer in Visual Studio look like this:

> Data Source= ******.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=******

The Connection String from Azure Portal look like this:

> Server=tcp:******.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: Also, If anyone wonder I have checked Firewall. I have added my IP address as Client IP address in Azure Portal, so I think it should be fine.

Comment: This connection string looks like a Azure SQL, not a MySQL ? If you are using Azure SQL, then use the System.Data.SqlClient, give a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Thank @Tony . You are right . I follow your instruction and it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Connection String from Azure Portal look like this:
>
> > Server=tcp:******.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

This is a SQL Server connection string. You cannot use MySqlConnector with this connection string. Are you sure you're using Azure Database for MySQL and copying the connection string from the right database?

Comment: Thank Bradley, You are right, I have fixed the problem